# Spring Integration: return a non null reply from an outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I have a a channel with 2 outbound-channel-adapters hooked to it, both returning a Message object containing the results of their activities.
This used to work until an upgrade to SI 2.1 was made. Now, I'm getting an error messages due to the fact that a method is returning a non null value.

Here's a code sample:

```
<integration:gateway id="notificationGateway"
                     default-request-channel="notificationRecordsFetcher" 
                     default-reply-channel="notifySupplier"
                     service-interface="com.supplier.NotificationGateway"/>

<!-- Submit the file to the supplier-->
<integration:channel id="notifySupplier"/>

<!-- Handle the secured transfer (first) -->
<integration:outbound-channel-adapter order="1" channel="notifySupplier" id="SupplierSecuredFileTransfer" ref="SubmitToSupplier" method="submit" />

<!-- Delete the notification records marked as successful (second) -->
<integration:outbound-channel-adapter order="2" channel="notifySupplier" id="deleteNotificationRecords" ref="databaseService" method="removeNotificationEntries" />
```

The adapter identified as "SupplierSecuredFileTransfer" takes a bunch of XML files, each represents a database record and send them using SFTP to a destination folder. It then marks the records that were successfully delivered and send them as a reply to the second adapter identified as "deleteNotificationRecords" which in turn reads the message payload updated by the first one and perform on it.
Now since the new restriction was introduced, I'm not able to pass information between the adapters.
Any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

What version did you migrate from?

Change the <outbound-channel-adapter/>s to <service-activator/>s, change channel to input-channel and set output-channel to "nullChannel".

Comment: Thought of doing that but the "SupplierSecuredFileTransfer" adapter has to handle the SFTP submission, thus will need to remain adapter (probably the SFTP adapter or gateway introduced in SI 2.1), and based on the outcome of the submission database entries will have to be removed.

Comment: Also I think it's 1.0 version of SI we migrated from